# slim 3 pass additional param to controller

Tags: php, slim-3

This is my original code:

```
 $app->post('/api/user', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) use ($tokenAuth) {      
    $tokenAuth->parseHeaders(); // validate token
    //...do stuff with $tokenAuth data
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(...)));
    return $response;
});
```

Notice the `use ($tokenAuth)` this allows me to use this object within the method.

How can I use this method below in the same manner?

```
$app->post('/api/user', \UserController::class . ':add');
```

which works fine when the route hits in the class UserController:

```
class UserController {
    public function add($request, $response, $args) { ...}
}
```

How can I pass `$tokenAuth` to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using middleware to authenticate on the route:

```
$mw = function($request, $response, $next){
    $tokenAuth = new \TokenAuth();
    $tokenAuth->parseHeaders();
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;
};

$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->post('/api/user', \UserController::class . ':add')->add($mw);

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register `$tokenAuth` and `UserController` to dependency manager and pass `$tokenAuth` to `UserController` via dependency injection merchanism. For example:

```
<?php 
namespace Your\Own\NameSpace;

use Your\Own\NameSpace\TokenAuth;

class UserController 
{
    private $tokenAuth;

    public function __construct(TokenAuth $tokenAuth) 
    {
        $this->tokenAuth = $tokenAuth;
    }

    public function add($request, $response, $args) 
    {
        $this->tokenAuth->parseHeaders();
        ... 
    }
}
```

In your dependency registration code (assuming using Pimple):

```
<?php

use Your\Own\NameSpace\TokenAuth;
use Your\Own\NameSpace\UserController;

$container[TokenAuth::class] = function ($c) {        
    return new TokenAuth();
};

$container[UserController::class] = function ($c) {
    $tokenAuth = $c->get(TokenAuth::class);
    return new UserController($tokenAuth);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at your original code, you can use `$tokenAuth` (and it works), it means that you defined it globally before.

So, in your `add` method, just declare it as a global variable: `global $tokenAuth;` then use it;

```
public function add($request, $response, $args) { 
    global $tokenAuth;
    $tokenAuth->parseHeaders();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a more slim 3 solution. As soon a global's come in to play i get the feeling it's starting to get 'hacky' so will leave this as a last resort.

Comment: using global variables in this manner is not recommended, since it is an object-reference. After a while you will struggle to identify where it was modified

Comment: I don't recommend using global variable, I just answer the question. :(